# Find the integral $\int f(x)f'''(x) dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I stuck to find the integral $\int f(x)f'''(x)\ dx$.

I found the rule $\int f(x)f'(x)\ dx=\frac{1}{2}f^2(x)+c$. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int f(x)f'''(x)dx=f(x)f''(x)-\int f'(x)f''(x)dx$$
Now:
$$\int f'(x)f''(x)dx=f'(x)^2-\int f''(x)f'(x)dx$$
So you can show:
$$\int f'(x)f''(x)dx=\frac12f'(x)^2$$
And so:
$$\int f'(x)f'''(x)=f(x)f''(x)-\frac12f'(x)^2+C$$

Comment: The second integration by parts is useless. $f'f''$ immediately integrates as $f'^2/2$.